# asp:ColorPickerExtender popupposition

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax

I got a problem. I try to add asp:ColorPickerExtender but when I set popUpPosition that doesn't change the position of my color picker position.

```
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCustomTheme" runat="server" CssClass="boutonCustomColor"
                                Width="100" Height="100" Style="margin: 5px; text-decoration: none; text-align: center;"
                                OnClick="btnCustomTheme_Click" Text="Custom"><img src="../images/plus.png" />

                            </asp:LinkButton><asp:TextBox ID="txtCustomColor" Style="display: none;" runat="server">

                            </asp:TextBox><asp:ColorPickerExtender ID="colorPicker" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtCustomColor" PopupButtonID="btnCustomTheme" PopupPosition="Center">
                            </asp:ColorPickerExtender>
```

Do you have an idea about this ?

Thank

Answer (score -1):

From [here](http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/how-to-use-ajax-colorpickerextender-in-Asp-Net-1032.aspx) :

> PopupPosition - Indicates where the color picker popup should appear
>   at the BottomLeft(default), BottomRight, TopLeft, TopRight, Left or
>   Right of the TextBox.

There is no `Center` value for `PopupPosition`

Comment: That change nothing, my popup continue to appear on the top left corner :/